# How to include a lib with dependencies to QT

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, include, qt4

I am creating a Visual C++ sample project where i need to include a third party library.

I added the lib and added the include directory.

But my problem is now, that the header files of the library have the following line in their header files:

```
#include <QtCore/QVector>
```

and the compiler error is:

```
error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'QtCore/QVector': No such file or directory
```

I have the used dlls, but I am stuck how to include them?!

Comment: have you tried just separating them?
 `#include <QTCore>; #include QVector;`

Comment: I solved it with installing Qt locally.

Comment: interesting, good work!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it with installing Qt locally and adding it to the `PATH`.